# Audio finger: write blocked, delayed writes

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, delay

My log cat is filled with messages like:

> 05-16 17:36:26.348: WARN/AudioFlinger(34): write blocked for 84 msecs, 1845 delayed writes, thread 0xc658

It actually delays the music when I click on the button. How to solve this problem?